# EXCEL 2013 VBA filtering issue

Tags: vba, excel

Dear Stackoverflow users,

I am having difficulty with something that seems simple enough to not cause this much trouble. I am trying to filter a Pivot Table based on the greater than equal to criteria, mentioned in the code below. Here is the code:

```
Sub KEEP_ON_FILE_DT_CLICK()
    Dim caches As Excel.SlicerCaches
    Set cache = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_KEEP_ON_FILE_DT")
    With cache
        For i = 1 To .SlicerItems.Count
            If .SlicerItems(i).Selected Then
                SelectedItem = .SlicerItems(i).Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("KEEP_ON_FILE_DT"). _
    ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("KEEP_ON_FILE_DT"). _
    PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlValueIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo, Value1:=SelectedItem
End Sub
```

For some reason, the last line where I actually apply the filter keeps giving me the following error message:

Run time error '5':
Invalid Procedure Call or argument

Kindly assist.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your pivot table does not allow for any such filters to be applied. There are many different ways / types of pivot tables and not all of them allow for such filters as `xlValueIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo`.

Yet, the following code should work under all circumstances:

```
Dim itmList As PivotItem
Dim dblDesiredValue as Long

dblDesiredValue = 32

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("KEEP_ON_FILE_DT").EnableMultiplePageItems = True        
For Each itmList In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("KEEP_ON_FILE_DT").PivotItems
    Select Case CDbl(itmList.Name)
    Case Is >= dblDesiredValue 
        itmList.Visible = True
    Case Else
        itmList.Visible = False
    End Select
Next itmList
```